# Check in policy within Visual Studio to restrict check-in after Sprint is over

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-2015

I need some help. If developers check-in the code even after the sprint is over, can any one of you please help me to draft the custom check in policy to restrict the developers from checking in the code when the sprint ends and until the next sprint starts. Also how want to impose another policy to check in the code only between two specific stages i.e., between the states of task is "approved" and "done". They should not be able to check-in after the task in marked as done. TFS 2015 and Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Afraid this could not be achieve by a custom check in policy.

And this is not a common usage of check in policy. Check-in policies usually **require the user to take actions** when they conduct a check-in to source control, for example a user can be required to associate a work item with a changeset during check-in.

However in your case, it's just simply restrict all developers check in their code during a specific stage. No matter which code or action there are provided. You could just use tf **permission** to do this. Using a powershell script change all users' permission to check in code during  a sprint ends and until the next sprint starts.

Comment: Can you please mention about "tf permission" in detail. Do I have to do it from visual studio(which version) or TFS? Can I get a sample of powershell script and where should I run the script?

Answer (score 0):

Use branching, then you can apply permissions to branches that are locked. If you're not branching, what are you doing?